# JavaScript Div Annimation

Tags: javascript, sorting

I would like to know if there is any specific way to get javaScript code to stop executing at some point so as to allow another called function to execute, for example in a sorting algorithm using Div's you call a function which annimates the swapping of the two Div's so you can visually see the sort taking place. I have tried using the setTimeout(c,t); however it does not seem to be be waiting and the Divs do not seem to be moving, if I however place an alert(""); within the moving code it seems to allow the move to take place with thousands to alerts popping up.

The code I have is as follows:

```
var q;
var w;
function move(x,y)
{
    q = x.style.top; // Keep a reference to the Top divs top element
    w = y.style.top; // Keep a reference to the Top divs top element
    doMove(x,y);
}
function doMove(topDiv, bottomDiv)
{
    //alert("in doMove " + topDiv);
    topDiv.style.top = parseInt(topDiv.style.top)+2+'px';
    bottomDiv.style.top = parseInt(bottomDiv.style.top)-2+'px';
    //alert("hi");
    if(bottomDiv.style.top != q && topDiv.style.top != w) // Check if the Top and Bottom divs have finally swapped
    {
        setTimeout(doMove(topDiv,bottomDiv),20); // call doMove in 20msec
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with your code is that in this line:

```
setTimeout(doMove(topDiv,bottomDiv),20);
```

You are calling `doMove` immediately and passing the value `undefined` as the first parameter to setTimeout.  Not entirely sure that the following will solve your problem, but I would recommend trying this:

```
setTimeout(function() { doMove(topDiv,bottomDiv); }, 20);
```